# Different web browsers behaviours

Tags: wordpress

just looking for someone that can help me to understand some behaviours I have on my PC browsers...

Problem: In a Wordpress site I'm unable to upload some plugins (Elementor PRO as example) BUT this will happen with Chrome and Edge, while with Firefox is working fine.

I tried to cancel all cache/history from the browser but I still have the problem.

Is someone able to give me an answer/suggestion on why this happen and how can/should do to solve it?

Regards
Giancarlo